# How to redirect and keep the previous URL with .htaccess?

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects, subdomain

I have created a subdomain and want to redirect it to a URL. But I want to keep the subdomain as the URL of the redirection. I have searched for it but none of them worked for me!

```
  Subdomain:   sub.domain.com    
  New URL:     10.10.10.10:8080
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/10\.10\.10\.10\:8080" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few fundamental problems with your last line.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/10\.10\.10\.10\:8080" [R=301,L]
```

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule .* http://10.10.10.10:8080 [R=301,L]
```

Of course, I assume that the IP address 10.10.10.10 in your example is just an example and that you are not trying to redirect to a private IP address that is not routable. As well, port 8080 is not an HTTP protocol and that you do have a web server answering that port.

Comment: Redirect works fine but the URL is changing to new URL: 10.10.10.10:8080. I want to keep the subdomain RUL.

Comment: @hamed Try a 302 and see what happens. If that does not work, then try removing the `[R=301,L]` entirely and see if that does what you want.

Comment: @hamed If 10.10.10.10 is another server, you may not have too many options. Redirect or Proxy, which I do not recommend - it is a security nightmare if you do not know what you are doing, may be all you can do.

Comment: It is the same. The URL is the 10.10.10.10.

Comment: Yes, 10.10.10.10 is another server which is not assigned to any domain. I think I should use proxy. I have tried proxy which worked fine but I couldn't redirect to port 8080.